# 複数APIの結果をまとめた配列を取得したい。（非同期）

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

複数URLの取得結果をまとめた配列にしたいのですが、下記のコードでは結果がNULLになってしまします。
ログではtitleは取れている形跡はみられますが、配列をNULL要素で作った後にWebから結果を取得しているように見えます。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="../lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var urls = [
    "http://localhost:8080/books/1.json",
    "http://localhost:8080/books/2.json",
    "http://localhost:8080/books/3.json",
  ];

  var getTitle = function (url) {
    $.get(url,
        function (data) {
          console.log("title:" + data.title);
          return {
            url: url,
            title: data.title
          }
        }
    );
  };

  var results = urls.map(getTitle);
  console.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results));
  $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(results));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

結果ログ

results: [null,null,null]
title:t12
title:t1
title:t13

results: [{url:"http://〜/1.json", title: t1},{ (略) },{ (略) }]
のような配列を取得するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get()` に渡している匿名関数を外に出してみます。

```
var onJsonGetComplete = function (data) {
    console.log("title:" + data.title);
    return {
        url: url,
        title: data.title
    }
};

var getTitle = function (url) {
    $.get(url, onJsonGetComplete);
};

var results = urls.map(getTitle);
```

`getTitle` から `return {...}` をしたかったのだと思いますが、実際には `$.get()` に渡した匿名関数から return しています。そして `getTitle` では何も return していませんから、 map の結果も全て null 、というわけです。

さて、それぞれが非同期に取得した結果をどこかに溜め込んでおいて、全部そろったところで目的の処理をする、という方法が考えられます。例えば・・・

```js
var urls = [
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"
];

var results = urls.map(function() { return null; });

urls.forEach(function (url, i) {
    $.get(url,
        function (data) {
            results[i] = {
                url: url,
                len: data.length
            };
            
            // 全て読み込めたかチェック
            var completed = results.every(function(res) {
                return res !== null;
            });
            if(completed) {
                $("body").text(JSON.stringify(results));
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Deferredと `$.when()` を使うと短く書けますが、配列での入出力ができないのでapplyやargumentsが必要でした。

```js
var urls = [
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"
];

var dfds = urls.map(function(url) {
  return $.get(url);
});

$.when.apply($, dfds).done(function(){
    var args = arguments;
    var results = urls.map(function(url, i) {
        var res = args[i][0];
        return {
            url: url,
            len: res.length
        };
    });
    $("body").text(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

ここまでに挙げたコードもシンプルとは言い難いですし、一部の取得に失敗したケースなどを考慮するとさらにややこしくなります。順番に取得したり、それぞれ独立して画面等への反映まで行うようにした方が、簡単に書けるのではないでしょうか。